# Can I set my subreport to print ONLY on certain pages?

Tags: acumatica, report-designer, acumatica-kb

I created a Check Remittance and Form with 6 subreports. Subreports 1-3 print details for Checks 1-18, Subreports 4-6 print details for Checks 19-37. On the first page of my report I would like to have Subreports 1-3 printed and on the 2nd page I would like subreports 4-6 printed. I tried putting them in different GroupHeaders and set the visibilty expression to print just on page 1 and just on page 2 using the PrintIndex Globals but that didnt work. I wonder if I could put them all in the group header and set their visibility expressions using the PrintIndex globals to print only on page 1 or 2. Anyone have any ideas? I tried variables too... no luck. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: If you add images of what you are seeing it may help to give you more options. What do you mean when you say it didn't work? Are subreports not printing at all? are they both always printing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by moving everything over to 2 page header sections